# Problem Getting Root URL in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, relative-path, base-tag

I'm having a problem getting the **root URL** with this **PHP function** I composed. I can get it, but **I have to make exceptions per server**, but I **desire one consistent function instead**. Can you show me how to fix it?

I stick it in the root folder of a given website, which on my Ubuntu workstation would be under /var/www/website, but on my CentOS server it might be under /home/me/website. It works on my workstation, but on the server I have to make a different version for some reason. Also, I have yet another version I had to make for yet another CentOS server that didn't seem to like the function as well. At the tail end of this question, I also list some background information on why I'm doing this in the first place.

**Workstation Version**

```
public function getRootURL() {
  $sTemp = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',__DIR__);
  $sTemp = str_replace($sTemp, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $sPageURL = (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $sPageURL .= ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80) ? ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $sRootURL = str_replace($sTemp,'',$sPageURL);
  $sRootURL = rtrim($sRootURL, '/') . '/';
  $sRootURL = (strpos(' ' . $sRootURL, '://') === FALSE) ? $sPageURL : $sRootURL;
  return $sRootURL;
}
```

**Server Version**

```
public function getRootURL() {
  $sTemp = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',__DIR__);
  $sTemp = str_replace($sTemp, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $sPageURL = (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $sPageURL .= ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80) ? ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $sRootURL = str_replace($sTemp,'',$sPageURL);
  $sRootURL = rtrim($sRootURL, '/') . '/';
  $sRootURL = (strpos(' ' . $sRootURL, '://') === FALSE) ? $sPageURL : $sRootURL;
  if (strpos(' ' . $sRootURL, 'mycentosserver.com')>0) {
    $sRootURL .= 'website/';
  }
  return $sRootURL;
}
```

On the server version, notice the "mycentosserver.com" if/then statement -- that's the difference.

**Alternative Server Version**

```
function getRootURL() {
  $sTemp = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',__DIR__);
  $sTemp = str_replace($sTemp, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $sPageURL = (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $sPageURL .= ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80) ? ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $sRootURL = str_replace($sTemp,'',$sPageURL);
  $sRootURL = rtrim($sRootURL, '/') . '/';
  $sRootURL = (strpos($sRootURL, '://') === FALSE) ? $sPageURL : $sRootURL;
  $sRootURL .= 'website2/'; // heck, I give up -- strange Apache problem on this server
  return $sRootURL;
}
```

**Background**

Normally I would use an MVC framework, but I have a client who wants to edit things when I'm gone, and who doesn't like MVC and doesn't understand it. He has simplistic PHP skills. So, I'm using an .htaccess that looks like this for pretty URLs, and ones where slashes can come on the end of the URL, alternatively:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

#No slash on the end of the url and not a real file/folder? then show x.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]*$ "$0.php" [nc]

#slashes on the end still and not a real file/folder, then remove them
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

#if still here, and not a real file/folder, then show x.php in the alternative way
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ "$1.php" [nc]
```

And am creating subfolders like _css, _js, _classes, etc. -- trying to keep things fairly simple. Each page has like PHP at the top and then  params at the bottom in the HTML. This is in an attempt at trying to eliminate spaghetti code. The client seems to like this, although I would prefer MVC, and especially for this root URL reason.

Note however with the .htaccess technique, there are cases where my HTML may not have proper relative pathing, such as someone adding a slash on the end of a URL, and therefore I must use a  tag in the HTML to clear things up with relative pathing. This is why the getRootURL() function must work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
function getRootURL() {
  $protocol   = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])? 'http' : 'https';
  $servername = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $serverport = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=='80'? '' : ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
  $path       = str_replace('\\', '/', substr(dirname(__FILE__), strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])));

  return $protocol . '://' . $servername . $serverport . $path;
}
```

`__FILE__` should work as long as the file is really in the root of the project (otherwise add a few more `dirname()`s.

---

Btw, if you are worried about "*someone adding a slash on the end of a URL*", why don't you just add `/?` to your RewriteRule?

Comment: What if a user requested a PHP file which is placed in a directory below the website root?
Suppose document root like /var/www while the website is placed under /var/www/website/ and so the root url is http://domain.com/website
and http request was for http://domain.com/website/a/b/c.php
your funciton can't get get http://domain.com/website/ out of the above? because it's about specific application URL not a server URL

Comment: @rahmanisback - Volomike said he's _sticking it_ [the root generating file] _in the root folder of a given website_. So `dirname(__FILE__)` will translate to the root directory of the website. That way, it's not application-specific. So as I mentioned in my answer - as long as the file with the function definition is in the root of the website, it should translate correctly.

Comment: @Czechnology: Thanks! I tested your code in 3 situations -- 2 completely CentOS configurations, and one Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop configuration (my workstation). **It worked in all 3 cases.** The only improvement was that I added an rtrim() check on the end to remove any ending slashes (if potentially there), and then tacked on another so that my BASE tag likes it. As well, I stuck this in a _classes subfolder and then removed "/_classes" out of the path.

Comment: @Czechnology: If you have some advice on the .htaccess file that is specific regarding any optimizations you might find, I'm eager to see it. I didn't quite understand your /? idea completely.

Comment: @Volomike, I don't have any optimizations, I usually add my nice urls directly in the .htaccess file in these cases (and I'm not saying that's a good/correct way to do it). But what I meant is that if you put `/?` on the end of the condition part of the _RewriteRule_, you don't have to worry about the optional slash at the end of the url.

Comment: @Czechnology - Thanks so much. I will give that a try and see what happens. I love optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your CentOS installation is not in the virtual host document root, while it is on your Ubuntu workstation.

In such case, having 2 different implementation of the function seem just natural to me.
Just put an IF condition discriminating on some ENV var or the SERVER_NAME and use one or another.